# Regex ignore patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, highlight

I'm trying to highlight some text but I want to exclude some patterns from being matched.

First I'm securing the text, replacing `&` with `&amp;` and `<` with `&lt;` then I look for matches and add the strong tag around it

```
html.replace(new RegExp(`${patterns.join('|')}`, 'g'), (match, group) => {
                return `<strong>${match}<strong>`;
            });
```

So if I have a text like `amp &` and try to highlight `amp` it becomes `<strong>amp<strong> &<strong>amp<strong>;`. How can I ignore  `&amp;` and `&lt;` from being matched?

I tried (new RegExp(`^(?!&amp;|&lt;)(${patterns.join('|')})`, 'g') but it's not working

Comment: ``new RegExp(`&(amp|lt);|${patterns.join('|')}`, 'g')`` and then ``return group === undefined ? `<strong>${match}<strong>` : match;``

Answer (score 0):

You can match and capture - all or part of - the strings you want to skip, and then check if that group matched in the arrow function used as a replacement:

```js
let html = "&lt; &amp; & amp";
const patterns = ['&', 'amp'];
const rx = new RegExp(`&(amp|lt);|${patterns.join('|')}`, 'g');
console.log(
    html.replace(rx, (match, group) => group === undefined ? `<strong>${match}<strong>` : match)
 );
```

Since `&(amp|lt);|` is the first alternative, the `(amp|lt)` will be the first group and it is assigned to `group` in your arrow function declaration, so if you check if `group` equals `undefined` you can learn if the undesired pattern was matched, and if it did, just return the whole match (`match`), else, return the tagged `match`.